# Closing submenu by clicking outside of main menu doesn't work in IE but works in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the a javascript code which close a mwnu with submenu made with `ul` and `li` elements.

A submenu is opened and if I click in other region of page or outside of menu, that submenu must be closed.

This script works only in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

The JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".item").on("click focusout", function(){
        $(".test").toggleClass("no-display");
    });       


    $(document).on("click", function(e){
        if(!$(".test").hasClass("no-display") && $(e.originalEvent.target).closest(".mega").length === 0) {
            $(".test").addClass("no-display");
        }
    });
});
```

And HTML code:

```
<ul class="mega">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li class='item'>Item2
        <ul class='test no-display'>
            <li>SubItem1</li>
            <li>SubItem2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
```

More better, I provide [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xemhT/1/) to see the issue in action

Comment: It's working in chrome on clicking "item2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach to this which is, I think, simpler:

```
$("html").click(function() {
    if(!$(".test").hasClass("no-display")) {
        $(".test").addClass("no-display");
    }
});
$(".test").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(".test").toggleClass("no-display");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use **stopPropagation()** for this. Write like this:

```
var box = $('.item');
        var sub = $('.test');

        box.click(function() {
            sub.show(); return false;
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            sub.hide();
        });

        box.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

​

Check this for more http://jsfiddle.net/xemhT/2/

Comment: `stopPropagation()` isn't a property.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if( $('.test').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.test').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this with BODY click listener, it works for me in IE:

```
jQuery('body').click(function(event) {
    var target = jQuery(event.target);
    // your code
});
```